# $resource and get array

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have an API which returns data with the following form (using tastypie):

```
{"meta":{
     "limit": 20, 
     "next": null, 
     "offset": 0, 
     "previous": null, 
     "total_count": 4}, 
     "objects": [
          {
           "id": 1, 
           "name": "name1", 
           "resource_uri": "/api/v1/operator/1", 
           "short_name": "NA1"
          },
          {
           "id": 2, 
           "name": "name2", 
           "resource_uri": "/api/v1/operator/2", 
           "short_name": "NA2"
          }, 
          ...
    ]
}
```

So I thought that to have my resource working, I should have used:

```
var Operator = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:8080\:8080/api/v1/operator/:operatorId',
    {operatorId:'@id'},
    {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(data).objects)
                return JSON.parse(data).objects;
            },
            isArray: true
        }
    });
```

But when I set isArray to true : I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Object #<g> has no method 'push'
```

If I set isArray to false, I have no error but my object also contains all meta datas for this request...

Not sure I understand correctly this $resource feature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `$resource` automatically converts the JSON string to object, you don't have to do call `JSON.parse()`.

Just do

```
var Operator = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:8080\:8080/api/v1/operator/:operatorId', {
    operatorId: '@id'
}, {
    query: {
        method: 'GET',
        transformResponse: function (data) {
            return data.meta.objects;
        },
        isArray: true
    }
});
```

Comment: According to the [official docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). The data  seems to represent http response body. 

`The transform function takes the http response body and headers and returns its transformed (typically deserialized) version.`

Answer (score 0):

The json data you are sending is not an array, and the `meta` property is not something created by angular framework. If you are expecting that it gets deserialized into the `objects` array you have to return only that part and `isArray` would work.

For now what @sza mentions to get the array you override `query` and return `data.meta.objects`